# Deserialize polypmorphic JSON types with key-based type names

Tags: java, json, jackson

Here is the sample JSON I want to deserialize with Jackson.

```
{
  "person": {
    "contacts": {
      "address": {
        "type": "Office",
        "street": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
        "city": "Mountain View",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "94043",
        "country": "United States"
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "Home",
        "emailAddress": "e.schmidt@google.com"
      },
      "phone": [
        {
          "type": "Mobile",
          "phoneNumber": "+1 888 555555"
        },
        {
          "type": "Home",
          "phoneNumber": "+1 888 1111111"
        }
      ],
      "website": {
        "type": "work",
        "webService": "URL",
        "webAddress": "www.google.com"
      }
    },
    "firstName": "Eric",
    "lastName": "Schmidt"
  }
}
```

The tricky bit to deserialize here is the contacts node.
Things to note:

1. contacts is a polymorphic abstract type (see POJOs below)
2. the type information (e.g., `addresss) is contained as a key in a wrapper
3. this wrapper can be an object if there is only one value (`email`, `address`, `website`) **OR** an array if there are multiple (`phone`)

Target POJOs:

```
public class Person
{
    public String firstName;
    public String LastName;
    public List<Contact> contacts; // mixes Address, Phone, Email, Website
}

public abstract class Contact {
    public Long id;
}

public class Phone extends Contact
{
    public String type;
    public String phoneNumber;
}

// other subtypes of Contact omitted for brevity
```

note: external requirements require that I use the abstract `Contact` type. I would rather deserialize directly to these POJOs *rather than having an intermediate `Contacts` POJO that the contact types hang off of and them manual mapping/converting to my List in another step.*

I've looked over many other jackson + polymorphic deserialization questions, but none seem to handle this case (#2 and #3 in particular).

I want to deserialize the contacts object to a `List<Contact>`.

What is proper application of `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` needed to achieve this?

(if anyone is interested this is [CapsuleCRM's JSON format](http://developer.capsulecrm.com/v1/resources/parties/))

Comment: http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/ Check this link to generate java class from json and make the necessary change

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that site generates a `Contacts` POJO which is the intermediate mapping/conversion I am trying to avoid by taking advantage of Jackson's polymorphic features.

Comment: Change the Contact in person to Object instead of class so you can type cast it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a custom deserializer and register it with Jackson. The implementation would check for initial start then parse accordingly. Think sax style processing.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, as it seems to be the only possible solution that meets my original requirements. In the end I parsed the JSON into intermediate POJOs and then munged it into the type-tree I wanted manually.